# How to avoid user getting back to a php page

Tags: php, html, cookies, back

I created a form where a user (not logged in) first of all registers his access in a building with the access' timestamp, then when he leaves he submits again his informations, the form shows him his informations (including arriving time) and allows him to insert leaving time.
After compleating the process, the database is updated also with leaving time and the browser is redirected to a home page.
My problem is that if the following person presses the "go-back button", he could change the leaving time of the previous person, and I want to avoid this.

Could a cookie mechanism help me?
I don't really have ideas of how to manage this problem.
I tried to set a coockie before the database update comes and that expires after the update, but with the "go back" button the page isn't refreshed, but it's taken from the cache, and the cookie isn't controlled.

Comment: Why is there no login, how does the user provide their identity then?

Comment: The user only submits his name, surname and email, so he can be contacted back in case of necessity, but it hasn't to register to the whole system.

Comment: So why are you worried about the back button then, when nothing is stopping _me_ from inputting _your_ name & email in the first place.

Comment: Theoretically the next person doesn't know name, surname and email of the previous one

Comment: What does "previous" have to do with this ... If I know _anyone's_ name & email, then I could insert that data whenever I want, no? Doesn't matter if they were the "previous" person, or there was five different people between us.

Comment: The application supposes no one lies and only inserts correct datas. When I enter a building and compile a paper sheet and put it in a basket nobody prevents me from stealing, destroying or modifying other sheets, but I'd never do something like that. It's just to avoid that someone else for accident finds a form already compiled by someone else

Answer (score 1):

You can not prevent user from clicking the back button of the browser and going back to the previous page.

But as a workaround, what you can do is when the user is redirected to the homepage you can close the current tab and open a new tab so the new tab doesn't have a previous page to go to.

```
$("#go-to-home-page").on("click", function(){
    window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com','_blank');
    window.close();
});
```